# Back up programs and user data from an old HDD to a new installation on an SSD

Tags: home-directory, deja-dup, data-recovery, clone, transfer

I have Ubuntu on my old HDD which is connected via USB to this system, and an SSD is built in to my notebook. At the moment I am running Ubuntu from a USB stick.

I have tried to clone my disk (change uiid, etc.), to transport the data with Deja Dup and much more. The result was nothing or strange things.

My idea is to copy the important data form the old system to the new (home and whatever), but I'm not permitted to do this.

Does anyone know of a tool which can do this or have an other idea?

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer about what "important files" you want to copy, and what error messages you get from trying to simply copy the files to the new installation? If you are trying to copy system files like from the /etc directory (which I wouldn't generally recommend) you would need to be root first.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm Hans; I did something like that and summarized my steps [here](http://cms.mooreworks.net/cms/bubbles4-or-swapping-a-linux-hdd-to-ssd.aspx). The overview is

1. Boot from some live cd.
2. dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc
3. Reboot from the live cd so the HDD partition table is valid.
4. sudo -s
5. mkdir a
6. mount /dev/sda1 a
7. mount --bind /dev a/dev
8. mount --bind /proc a/proc
9. mount --bind /sys a/sys
10. chroot a
11. update-grub

Reboot and you should be good to go.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used the dd command to directly clone an older hdd to a replacement. You will need to boot to an ubuntu cd or another linux device than the ones you are cloning.
Then from the command prompt use the dd command. I have to warn you that using any command in the terminal can be risky if you make a mistake, but dd is particularly dubious since it can overwrite an entire disk. That said... the command looks like this.

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

The "if" stands for input file. This is the source drive you are copying FROM.

The "of" stands for output file. This is the destination drive you are copying TO.

You can find a more detailed description here:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19141/clone-a-hard-drive-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/
 and by viewing the man pages for dd.

Comment: Ok. Upon reading this a second time (and after an edit), I think I misunderstood the question. My answer covers cloning.